# Used is pronounced as /juːzd/ or /juːst/?

Tags: pronunciation

Different dictionary pronounces `used` differently.

One as `/juːst/` http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/used

Other as `/juːzd/` http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/used

So which one is correct?

Comment: *I /juːzd/ soap to wash the dishes* but *I /juːst/ to wash the dishes without soap.*

Comment: Exactly. With "to" following, the "d" sound is subsumed in the "t" sound. There's some fancy linguistic term for this phenomenon, which I don't remember.  Anyway, "used to " in speech (AmE) is approximately "yoosta".

Comment: Two different definitions. Two different pronunciations. The Cambridge Dictionary link you gave actually has both definitions and both pronunciations. Read it more carefully. (The Oxford dictionary contains both, too, but the other definition is listed under *use* and is relatively [hard to find](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/use).)

Answer (score 3):

/juːzd/ is the past tense of the verb "use".  /juːst/ with "to" following (but pronouncing only one of the /t/s) expresses an habitual or customary past tense of a following verb.